# Ubercart review order button redirects to cart page, does not allow checkout

Tags: 7, ubercart

I am using Ubercart 3.3, Secure Pages latest dev, and Drupal 7.18.

When I go to the site, login, and add a product to my cart all goes well.  I then go to the cart page which shows correctly and I click checkout.  It then redirects me to the checkout page where I fill in my information and choose paypal as my payment of choice.  When I'm all done I click review order at the bottom of the form and it redirects me back to the cart page instead of the review order page.

To make matters worse, after that happens I can no longer get back to the checkout page, every time I click checkout it just redirects me back to the cart page.

Some things i've checked:

1. User 0 is in the database
2. Clearing cache
3. Truncating the cache tables
4. Try a different product
5. Applied patches Secure Pages requires
6. Adding `$conf['https'] = TRUE;` at the bottom of my `settings.php` file

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It actually turned out that I **had a product in my cart that was no longer on the site**, and my theme did not have the proper messages outputting.  I switched the theme back to Bartik and got a message saying there were products in my cart that were no longer available.

Answer (score 1):

Some other things to try -

- Check your webserver logs (eg Apache log) for errors
- Check your Drupal watchdog logs (admin/reports/dblog - you may need to enable this and then repeat the issue to log errors)
- Check your Paypal processor is configured correctly, and that no errors are showing in Paypal admin interface
- Switch to another payment processor (eg test gateway) & disable Paypal

These aren't answers, but they may help you find your own solution.

Comment: No errors in watchdog, disabling paypal didn't fix it. Not sure how to check apache logs.

Comment: It's specific to your hosting environment, so you may need to consult your hosting company if you're on a commercial hosting setup. You may not even be using Apache, but it's common. If you're on Debian, look first in /var/log/apache2

Answer (score 0):

In my case changing the theme to Bartik, everything works fine. So there must be something in the custom theme that is preventing submission. Of to check now.

Answer (score 0):

In fact, you need to add stock to make it work. If the stock is set to 0, there is nothing to buy.